# Magento2 changes not deployed

Tags: magento2, deployment, workflow

I am working with Magento2 and have the problem, that my changes are only visible after a full `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US`.

**Prerequisites:**

- Magento 2.1.0
- Linux VM with Apache / PHP7
- Developer mode active
- Caches inactive and flushed

I changed a html-file for a ko-template in a custom module, and tried to see the changes in frontend without a full static deploy. But it still displayed the old code. According to different people i asked and digged through blogs / docs i found out, i should remove these directories:

- pub/static/frontend
- var/di
- var/view_preprocessed
- var/generation

The .htaccess in pub/static was not removed. But after doing this, no JS / CSS files were available in browser and also were nothing was generated in pub/static/frontend except the _requirejs directory.

I ran out if ideas and working like this is really slow and annoying. According to other developers, it should work like this. What is the correct workflow here?

I apprechiate your help!

Comment: From my experience so far, all the .html and .js files do not update unless you do a static-deploy after deleting the generated file in `pub/static`. What **should** happen is a symlink to the working file should be created when you are working on a file, but that doesn't happen for me. My work around is just to edit the .html and .js files in pub/static till i get what i need and then copy that code over to the file in my theme.
But this is just my experience so far, so it's not a real answer.

Comment: I posted my solution,  as it works now for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i got it working. I will post here a general guide for the developer mode and what needs to be done. With the shown shell commands i assume that you are in your Magento2 root directory.

To get the developer workflow up and running, there are a few things to do.
First, activate developer mode in magerun: `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`. To be sure developer mode is active, check your `app/etc/env.php` if the developer mode is set: `'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'`. After this, also add / uncomment this line in .htaccess and pub/.htaccess `SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer`. After this, remove all your static and generated content:
`rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/generation/* var/cache/* pub/static/*`

**IMPORTANT:**
Check that no uncommented content is after this command!
`SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer #Comment` will not work. This caused the problem in my case, because in the default htaccess a comment exists.

Original pub/.htaccess line: `#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE default # or production or developer`